# Including isNil in lodash chain

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a collection of entities like this:

```
var entities = [
  {
    location: null,
    label: 'xyz'
  },
  {
    location: {
      city: 'city'
    },
    label: 'xyz'
  }
  {
    label: 'xyz'
  }
];
```

Trying to filter out entities with location = `null`, `undefined` or not existing at all. Using lodash.

When testing the location of the first entity in this way, it's returning the correct answer `true`:

```
_.isNil(_(entities[0]).get('location'));
```

but when I trying to include the isNil in chain, it returns `Cannot read property 'valueOf' of null` error:

```
_(entities[0]).get('location').isNil
```

Can isNil included somehow in the lodash chain?

here is the issue: https://codepen.io/neptune01/pen/qjxJwr

I'll need to use it somehow in this way:

```
_(entities).omitBy(_.get('location').isNil)
```

or

```
_(entities).omitBy(_(entity).get('location').isNil)
```

Comment: Why would you need to chain it?

Comment: @charlietfl I just want to use this chain as callback in an omitBy from an outer chain.

Comment: Well `isNil()` it doesn't work without passing in the value you want to check. Look at the source https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.4/lodash.js#L11987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isNil()` is not chainable.

See a complete list of non-chainable methods **[here](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.4/lodash.js#L1616)**.

You can use it like this, for your particular problem:

```
_.omitBy(entities, (el) => _.isNil(el.location))
```

```js
var entities = [{
    location: null,
    label: 'xyz'
  },
  {
    location: {
      city: 'city'
    },
    label: 'xyz'
  }
];

console.log(_.omitBy(entities, (el) => _.isNil(el.location)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```